# What do the Google Maps Terms of Service mean in practice for an iOS app developer?

Tags: ios, google-maps

I want to use the MapViewController in an iOS app (to allow the user to find the adress of where he is currently at) and came across the ["Google Maps Terms of Service for iPhone SDK"](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html), but I am a bit lost what some of this means in practice, i.e. what do I need to be aware of and what do I need to do when using a MapViewController. Specifically:

> 9.2 Reporting. You must implement those reporting mechanisms that Google
>   has set forth and may update from time
>   to time in these Terms and in the Maps
>   API Documentation. For example, as
>   specified in the Maps API
>   Documentation, you agree to provide
>   reports to Google if your Maps API
>   Implementation enables a device to
>   detect its own location through use of
>   a sensor (including but not limited to
>   GPS, cell triangulation, WiFi or
>   similar functionality) to display the
>   location of the device on a map or to
>   calculate a route.

Obviously I am enabling the device to detect its own location by showing the map with the current location marker. I got lost trying to find some details on what that "reporting" means and if and what kind of it I am supposed implement.

Thanks,
Timo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from [Google Maps API Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#keysystem):

> **How does the Google Maps APIs key system work?**
>
> Google Maps API keys are only required when using the *JavaScript Maps API v2 and the Maps API for Flash* [emphasis added].
>
> In order to obtain a Google Maps API key, you must sign in to your Google Account and agree to our Terms of Service. There is no limit to the number of keys you may obtain under a single account.

When you use MKMapView as part of the iPhone SDK, you are using it under Apple's license with Google for the map service.  Therefore you do not need to separately agree to the Google Maps API Terms of Service or implement any functionality to meet this requirement.

Comment: Apple says otherwise: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html

Comment: This statement in the document is required under section 9.3 of the Maps API TOS. Your obligations as an application developer apply to many aspects of the TOS, but not all because some of it is geared towards to API/Framework developers. The requirement to report the use of sensor data to Google is an implementation detail that is handled via the API. If you read 9.3 and then re-read 9.2, it becomes more obvious that this applies to Apple for their iOS framework implementation. You are just using the framework and are therefore not responsible for that technical detail.

Comment: @Timo: If you found this to be the answer you were looking/the accepted answer, I'd hope you could mark it as accepted.  I'm trying to build up my reputation on StackOverflow and appreciate the help.  Thanks, Alex

Comment: Sure thing, just wanted to wait a bit in case someone else answered as well.