# Google Map API for Android: TOS Reporting requirement

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an Android application that is currently using the v1 version of the Maps API.  I'm looking to upgrade to v2, but in reading the terms of service I came across this provision:

> 9.2 Reporting. You must implement those reporting mechanisms that Google has set forth and may update from time to time in these Terms and in the Maps APIs Documentation. For example, as specified in the Maps API Documentation, you agree to provide reports to Google if your Maps API Implementation enables a device to detect its own location through use of a sensor (including but not limited to GPS, cell triangulation, WiFi or similar functionality) to display the location of the device on a map or to calculate a route.

I'm wondering if this means there are additional configuration or features I would need to implement.  I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243133/what-do-the-google-maps-terms-of-service-mean-in-practice-for-an-ios-app-develop) was asked a year ago for the iPhone and the answer was "nothing" , but I couldn't find any discussion anywhere on how it applied to the Android side, since (I believe) the v1 API didn't require to you agree to these terms.

For the record, the FAQ on this question (found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_reporting)) only provides links to guidance for the javascript, flash, and static API versions, not for Android.  It also does not state explicitly that use of the Android API is exempt.

I am hoping the answer is still "nothing", mainly because I can find nothing in the v2 API that would allow me to programmatically provide this data even if I was willing to provide it (which I am, just making a point).  But I feel compelled to ask because the TOS language is vague enough to apply to Android, and the v2 API is still relatively new so maybe nobody has bothered with it yet.  I know this is less of a programming question and more of a legal question, but if there is in fact something that needs to be done in the implementation, then that makes it relevant programming-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still "nothing" regarding reporting - this is automatic, but you need to consider [Attribution Requirements](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#attribution_requirements).